# Sorting array gives me error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an `array` of `structs`. In the `struct` I have two `NSDate` objects: `prop1` and `prop2`. I'm trying to sort `prop1` from  newest to oldest date/time. And I want `prop2` to also get ordered based on `prop1`. (I will also want to do vice versa.)

```
struct Item {
    let prop1 : NSDate
    let prop2 : NSDate
}

var myItem = [Item]()

myItem.insert(Item(prop1: myDateSecond, prop2: anotherDateSecond), atIndex: 0)
myItem.insert(Item(prop1: myDateThird, prop2: anotherDateThird), atIndex: 0)
myItem.insert(Item(prop1: myDateFirst, prop2: anotherDateFirst), atIndex: 0)

myItem.sort { $0.prop1 < $1.prop1 }
```

At the last line of code, I get the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's `array` in `array.sort`?

Comment: My bad. I just changed it to `myItem.sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing two dates you have to use NSDate method [compare](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:):

```
struct Item {
    let prop1 : NSDate
    let prop2 : NSDate
}

var myItem = [Item]()

myItem.insert(Item(prop1: myDateSecond, prop2: anotherDateSecond), atIndex: 0)
myItem.insert(Item(prop1: myDateThird, prop2: anotherDateThird), atIndex: 0)
myItem.insert(Item(prop1: myDateFirst, prop2: anotherDateFirst), atIndex: 0)

myItem.sort{$0.prop1.compare($1.prop1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please include the longer version of `sort`? This one is a bit confusing and hard to read. Thanks!

Comment: Thats basic Swift syntax. I've posted the documentation's link to the compare method.

Comment: I'm talking about `$0.prop1.compare($1.prop2)`